# I download an image from the internet with a service. How do i show it?

Tags: java, android, service

I download an image from the internet with a service. When the download is complete it changes the textview. I tried this on my device and it works.

Now i want the imageview in my layout to change to the downloaded image.

ServiceFile java

```
public class ServiceFile extends IntentService {
    private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
    public static final String URL = "urlpath";
    public static final String FILENAME = "filename";
    public static final String FILEPATH = "filepath";
    public static final String RESULT = "result";
    public static final String NOTIFICATION = "be.ehb.arnojansens.fragmentexampleii";

    public ServiceFile() {
        super("ServiceFile");
    }

    // will be called asynchronously by Android
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String urlPath = intent.getStringExtra(URL);
        String fileName = intent.getStringExtra(FILENAME);
        File output = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                fileName);
        if (output.exists()) {
            output.delete();
        }

        InputStream stream = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {

            java.net.URL url = new URL(urlPath);
            stream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());
            int next = -1;
            while ((next = reader.read()) != -1) {
                fos.write(next);
            }
            // successfully finished
            result = Activity.RESULT_OK;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        publishResults(output.getAbsolutePath(), result);
    }

    private void publishResults(String outputPath, int result) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(NOTIFICATION);
        intent.putExtra(FILEPATH, outputPath);
        intent.putExtra(RESULT, result);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

This is my main activity where i have my textview and the future imageview

```
private TextView textView;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                String string = bundle.getString(ServiceFile.FILEPATH);
                int resultCode = bundle.getInt(ServiceFile.RESULT);
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Download complete. Download URI: " + string,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    textView.setText("Download done");
                    // here i shoud load my image i downloaded with my service
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Download failed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    textView.setText("Download failed");
                }
            }
        }
    };

   public void service (View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceFile.class);
        // add infos for the service which file to download and where to store
        intent.putExtra(ServiceFile.FILENAME, "index.html");
        intent.putExtra(ServiceFile.URL,
                "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars#mediaviewer/File:Star_Wars_Logo.svg");
        startService(intent);
        textView.setText("Service started");


    }
```

Comment: Why not use Picasso lib?

Comment: It has to be like this for my assignment

Answer (score 0):

Better to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) than to pass the information per Intent.

If not, your service should write the image into a readable folder and you can send by intent the Uri to that file to whom it concerns with [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for instance